# CSS Grid Heigth no se adapta al contenido

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

es la primera vez que uso CSS Grids y estoy teniendo problemas para adaptar el height total de la grid al contenido.
Esta grid es una row en la grid principal con auto.
Me pasa lo mismo en todos los casos que le asigno altura auto en las propiedades de la grilla.
Pretendo que la altura se adapte al contenido y no ocurre.
En este caso el botón no queda completamente dentro de la grilla.

[image: Este es el ejemplo del código]

```
  <div class="gridForm">
     <p id="titleFormulario">Sumate a nuestra alternativa</p>    
     <form id="formulario">                    
         <div class="form-group">                    
             <input name="Nombre" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input name="Lugar" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Lugar">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input name="Email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Email">
         </div>
         <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
             <span id="responseMessage"></span>
         </div>      
         <div class="divBtnEnviar">
         <button id="btnEnviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button> 
         </div>                     
     </form>
```

```
.gridForm
{    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 30% 70%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: La verdad es que lo que tu tienes no es una "cuadrilla", sino dos celdas una debajo de otra. Es posible que no entienda bien que es lo que quieres conseguir. De todos modos: existe la palabra clave `max-content` que podría ser lo que tu necesitas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Answer (score 1):

Te olvidaste de cerrar el div principal con la clase "gridForm" por eso no puede obtener bien su height

```
 <div class="gridForm">
     <p id="titleFormulario">Sumate a nuestra alternativa</p>    
     <form id="formulario">                    
         <div class="form-group">                    
             <input name="Nombre" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input name="Lugar" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Lugar">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input name="Email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Email">
         </div>
         <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
             <span id="responseMessage"></span>
         </div>      
         <div class="divBtnEnviar">
         <button id="btnEnviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button> 
         </div>                     
     </form>   
</div>
```

Solo agregué una etiqueta "`</div>`" luego de la de form.